# UnsatisfiedLinkError, no such file or directory but file exists

Tags: java

I am trying to run my Java program but getting an error about a `.so` not existing.

I have specified the libs folder by using `-Djava.library.path=libs` and -`DLD_LIBRARY_PATH=libs`

As a result, when I run the file the console spits out the correct path of the file but says `No such file or directory`.

It's frustrating because the file does exist.

I have also tried running the application as `sudo` with no luck.

How can I get Java to recognise that this file does indeed exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the java.library.path explicitly in the code, this has sometimes worked for me where command line flags have failed

`System.setProperty("java.library.path", path);`

or try setting the path explicitly, in quotes
-Djava.library.path="/full/path/to/lib-folder"

Comment: I can't do that, as I don't have access to the code.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. Could there be something wrong with the file re: permissions?

Comment: That's possible I suppose you could try a `sudo chmod 555 filename`, but without having source code to see how it is loading the library, it will be hard to determine the issue.